WPF Databinding in Listview
I have the following ListView that I wish to bind to a custom list in my viewmodel:
<ListView x:Name="listviewPlayers"  ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" Height="200">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="235">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Content ="Name" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10"></Label>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="235">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content ="Score" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10"></Label>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="235">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content ="Games" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10"></Label>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:MainPageViewModel">
                    <Grid Height="25">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black">
                            </Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding CurrentScore}" FontSize="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black">
                            </Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding GamesWon}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Foreground="Black">
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

In my viewmodel I have Players:
public ObservableCollection<Player> Players
    {
        get { return players; }
        set
        {
            players = value;
            foreach (Player p in players)
            {
                PlayerNames.Add(p.Name);
            }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Players"));
        }


    }

And a Player looks like this:
public class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    private string name = "";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name")); }
    }

    private string currentScore = "0"; 

    public string CurrentScore
    {
        get { return currentScore; }
        set
        {
            currentScore = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentScore"));
        }
    }

    private string gamesWon = "0";

    public string GamesWon
    {
        get { return gamesWon; }
        set { gamesWon = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GamesWon")); }
    }

What am I doing wrong with my ListView DataTemplate bindings? I have set this on the MainWindow:
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainPageViewModel}"

At the moment the ListView looks like this:

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Mike

Do not set the ItemTemplate property of the ListView, but instead the CellTemplate or the DisplayMemberBinding property of the GridViewColumns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

I've removed the DataType from here if that's what you mean?

But I still get the same result
The gridviewcolumns are just the headers

You must not set the ItemTemplate property of the ListView.
Set the GridViewColumns' DisplayMemberBinding property instead.
<ListView x:Name="listviewPlayers" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" Height="200">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="235" Header="Name"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="235" Header="Games"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CurrentScore}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="235" Header="Score"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GamesWon}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

If you want to explicitly set the UI elements of the header and the cell content, write the GridViewColumn declarations like this:
<GridViewColumn Width="235">
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
    </GridViewColumn.Header>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>


The Gridview is for the column headers, which is fine. It's the DataTemplate of the ListView.ItemTemplate that isn't binding to the items in the List

As said, you must not set the ItemTemplate of a ListView. Data templating is done by the CellTemplates. See the edited answer.

Thank you - that is far simpler than not using GridView

And it is how a ListView is supposed to be used. You would only set the ItemTemplate of a ListBox, not a ListView.

I was converting code back form Xamarin - which I expect is why I ended up doing that. Thanks again!
